# ASP.Net API Help page no longer works after upgrade to Web API 2.1

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api2

After an upgrade to Web API 2.1, my help pages no longer work.  Any suggestions?

I haven't changed anything, and I'm not using Glimpse

But when I execute

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.DocumentationProvider = Configuration.Services.GetDocumentationProvider();
    return View(Configuration.Services.GetApiExplorer().ApiDescriptions);
}
```

All of the Descriptions in ApiDescriptions return  Documentation: "No documentation available."

Nothing has changed in my controllers or views.

Any ideas where to start looking?

While I've verified that I have the "XML documentation file" in the build properties checked, the xml file is no longer being generated.

**Edit**
After following sunil's suggestion, I have gotten a little further.  In HelpPageConfig I uncommmented the code

```
config.SetDocumentationProvider(new XmlDocumentationProvider(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/XmlDocument.xml")));
```

So I'm now getting descriptions from my ApiDescriptions, but now in

```
    private static void GenerateResourceDescription(HelpPageApiModel apiModel, ModelDescriptionGenerator modelGenerator)
    {
        ResponseDescription response = apiModel.ApiDescription.ResponseDescription;
        Type responseType = response.ResponseType ?? response.DeclaredType;
```

the apiModel.ApiDescription.ResponseDescription is null which causes an error.  The ApiDescription does have values, so I can probably work around this, but is there something just not being initialized?

In addition, if I run a copy of my old version (with the original Web API) first, the code works even though they are now different solutions.

Comment: First I would check whether your documentation IS available: does your XML documentation file exist (the one from Project-Properties, Build, Output)?

Comment: When you upgrade all your help page changes get overwritten. Like @Dunken said, check if this line in `config.SetDocumentationProvider(new XmlDocumentationProvider(
    HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/XmlDocument.xml")));` is enabled in `HelpPageConfig.cs `

Comment: That does seem to fix it, although now I'm not sure how it worked before the upgrade because it wasn't there before.  Now I just have to figure out what happened to HelpPageApiModel ApiDescription.ResponseDescription so I can get my add-in "A Simple Test Client..." to work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and after 3 hours of going through every change performed by my upgrade to web api v2 I realized it had nothing to do with the upgrade.

My issue was that I had to update the NuGet [SDammann.WebApi.Versioning](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SDammann.WebApi.Versioning) from **v2.0.0.3** to the latest version **v2.5**! I assume this fixes the problem because the VersionedApiExplorer is fixed for WebApi v2.